# Gulp - Inject js from one file into another without Browserify

Tags: javascript, gulp

Using `gulp`, what is a proper way to inject one js file into another?

I know about `gulp-browserify`, but that wraps each `require`'d file in it's own IIFE so variables are no longer global and, unfortunately, I need them to be global.

I know I can also concat all JS files into one, but I would like to generate separate JS files.

Is there a way to simply `include` the contents of one file within another where I can specify the concatenation in the JS file itself instead of in Gulp's configuration file?